# Column not found: 1054 Champ 'DAY(datep)' inconnu

Tags: laravel

I have a pointages table that means declaration of the days working for the salaries I take an example of a single salarie salarie1, who works in a chantier 1 which tinker ouvrage 1 in a date x and Overtime, for my purpose I wants to return Total amount due by the salarie to the company in the 1st fortnight. but its give me this error  Column not found: 1054 Champ 'DAY(datep)' inconnu plz help
[image]

**SalarieController.php**

```
public function payer(){ 
      return DB::table('salaries')
      ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
      ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) as sold')
      ->where('DAY(pointages.datep)>0 AND DAY(pointages.datep)<16')
      ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
      ->get();
    }
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @NicoHaase 'DAY(datep)' inconnu

Comment: What does "Inconnu" mean? That does not look like a question to me

Comment: @NicoHaase thx for answer i will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

`DAY` is a `mysql` inbuilt function that is why you need to use `DB::raw`

```
 return DB::table('salaries')
      ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
      ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) as sold')
      ->where( DB::raw('DAY(pointages.datep)>0 AND DAY(pointages.datep)<16')) // use DB::raw here
      ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
      ->get();
```

References:
[Mysql -> Date Time functions -> Day function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)

[Laravel -> Queries -> Raw Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: error no longer displayed but sold it gives nothing